# What could cause an action in remix.js from not being triggered only on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, remix.run

I have a functional component which is taking an uploaded image and submitting it through a form. This all works perfectly on browsers on my laptop (Mac OS), however, the action never gets triggered on Chrome/Safari on my iOS device.

Here is the form:

```
<Form className="basis-2/12 flex justify-center items-center" ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="fileUrl" value={originalPhoto as string} />
  <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value={photoName as string} />
  <button className="btn btn-outline text-orange-200 border-orange-200" disabled={!originalPhoto} type="submit">
    Restore Photo
  </button>
</Form>
```

and here is the handleSubmit function:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault()
      setLoading(true)
      console.log('form ref >>> ', formRef.current?.submit)
      formRef.current?.submit()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Encountered an error ', err)
    }
  }
```

As you can see I have added some console logs. There are no errors being logged and the submit function is present on the browser in iOS. However, the action below doesn't triggered on mobile devices and no logs are presented. What could cause this?

```
export let action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
  console.log('CALLED ACTION')
  try {
    const formData = await request.formData()
    const fileUrl = formData.get('fileUrl') as string
    const fileName = formData.get('fileName') as string

    const replicateAPIKey = process.env.REACT_APP_REPLICATE_KEY

    const response = await restorePhoto(fileUrl, replicateAPIKey as string)

    if (response) {
      let newPhoto = await response.json()
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        return json({ error: newPhoto }, response.status)
      } else {
        return json({ restoredImage: newPhoto, originalPhoto: fileUrl, fileName })
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return json({ error: 'There was an unexpected error processing your request. Please try again later.' }, 500)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your submit function looks really strange. It looks like the entire thing could be just: `onSubmit={() => setLoading(true)}`. I wonder if manually calling `submit` on the form from inside a submit handler (where you've already called `preventDefault())` is the reason iOS is behaving differently.

Comment: Not quite sure I follow, handleSubmit is getting triggered however it does not trigger the action when reaching formRef.current?.submit()

Comment: So maybe iOS doesn’t like JS triggering a form submission. But the thing is, you don’t need it to. You’re calling preventDefault on the original user event and then manually calling submit again right after. What if you just didn’t call preventDefault (and formRef.current?.submit) at all?

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Cheers